# How can I implement autonomous navigation on a robot using only an RPlidar A1 sensor and an MPU6050 IMU?

Tags: slam, autonomous-car

I am attempting to build an autonomous robot using an RPlidar A1 sensor and an MPU6050 IMU. However, I do not have odometry sensors, which are commonly used for autonomous navigation. I am interested in implementing autonomous navigation using only the RPlidar A1 and MPU6050.

I am looking for an example of  Ideally, the example would include details on how to integrate the sensor data, build a map, and plan and execute a navigation path.

I am looking for a clear and concise explanation of how to perform autonomous navigation using only these sensors. Additionally, I would appreciate recommendations for specific algorithms, resources, or open-source projects that I can refer to for further guidance.

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* José, but I'm afraid that *Unbounded Design Questions* are off-topic because there are many ways to solve any given design problem. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*, so questions which ask for a list of approaches or a subjective recommendation on a method (for how to build something, how to accomplish something, what something is capable of, etc.) are off-topic. Please take a look at [ask] & [about] for more information on how stack exchange works.

Comment: Thank you for making the question slightly more explicit. But you're still asking for an example implementation, a description of how to do it and further recommendations. All these are generally still unbounded and subjective.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Hector SLAM without Odometry and IMU data as well. The ONLY prerequisite is that you have a LIDAR that publishes data.

The Hector SLAM algorithm works by using Laser Scan matching, and then builds the world based on the points that it receives from the LIDAR. By matching the points from consecutive LIDAR frames, it is able to ascertain the transformation between the frames and therefore also calculate its own odometry (based on changes in it's POSE).

You can easily clone the repository, setup your robot with the correct frames and use information from the A1 RPLidar. There are quite a few tutorials on getting this working without a hassle that already exist on YouTube and other sources :)

Wish you the best of luck.